# How to generate SQL code from Google Sheet

Tags: sql, google-sheets, join, concatenation, textjoin

I have a google Sheets that looks like this :

```
ID | City | Capital | Country
-------------------------------
5  | Paris | Yes | France
8  | Madrid| Yes | Spain
```

I would like to find a way to generate this kind of code for each line

```
 update database set city='Paris' and Country='France' where id=5
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
   insert into database(city,country) values('Paris','France');
```

I would like to generate a big file that concatenate all the SQL queries like the one above (one for each row), so I can just update my database with this.

Comment: You've almost done it already. Just put the sql in a column on the sheet and use concatenation to fill in the variable data from the relative cells.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
="update database set city='"&B2&"' and Country='"&D2&"' where id="&A2&"
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
   insert into database(city,country) values('"&B2&"','"&D2&"');"
```